# Pandas rolling() with groupby() changes index in strange ways

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numppy as np

iterables = [[1,2],['2011Q4','2012Q1','2012Q2','2012Q3','2012Q4','2013Q1','2013Q2','2013Q4']]

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((16,1)), columns=['val'], \
                index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables,names=['id','date']))
```

If I want to create a lag of `val` then I would do this:

```
data['val_lag1'] = data.groupby(level=0)['val'].shift(1)
```

which yields

```
                val  val_lag1
id date                      
1  2011Q4  0.215183       NaN
   2012Q1  0.929456  0.215183
   2012Q2  0.171601  0.929456
   2012Q3  0.387254  0.171601
   2012Q4  0.805295  0.387254
   2013Q1  0.592925  0.805295
   2013Q2  0.446619  0.592925
   2013Q4  0.962464  0.446619
2  2011Q4  0.723046       NaN
   2012Q1  0.840808  0.723046
   2012Q2  0.249003  0.840808
   2012Q3  0.306059  0.249003
   2012Q4  0.199025  0.306059
   2013Q1  0.815567  0.199025
   2013Q2  0.835140  0.815567
   2013Q4  0.322251  0.835140
```

However, when I try to do essentially something very similar with `rolling()` it doesn't work because of it duplicates one level of the index in the process. That is, it is not possible to assign

```
 data['val_ma4'] = data.groupby(level=0)['val'].rolling(4).mean()
```

as would seem natural/obvious because `data.groupby(level=0)['val'].rolling(4).mean()` now has a third level index:

```
id  id  date  
1   1   2011Q4         NaN
        2012Q1         NaN
        2012Q2         NaN
        2012Q3    0.466110
        2012Q4    0.392576
        2013Q1    0.408187
        2013Q2    0.432501
        2013Q4    0.600802
2   2   2011Q4         NaN
        2012Q1         NaN
        2012Q2         NaN
        2012Q3    0.535583
        2012Q4    0.463489
        2013Q1    0.639357
        2013Q2    0.683905
        2013Q4    0.686587
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

I can get rid of the extra index level but why does it appear and why do I have to do this? It doesn't make sense to me that I should have to do this:

```
xx = data.groupby(level=0)['val'].rolling(4).mean()
data['val_ma4'] = xx.unstack().groupby(level=0).mean().stack()
```

Comment: A quick google reveals that it is a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14420) since 2016. And suggestions show to use `apply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need to use `apply()`:

```
data['val_ma4'] = data.groupby(level=0)['val'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(4).mean())
```

And you achieve your desired output:

```
                val  val_lag1   val_ma4
id date                                
1  2011Q4  0.071332       NaN       NaN
   2012Q1  0.738045  0.071332       NaN
   2012Q2  0.578402  0.738045       NaN
   2012Q3  0.670338  0.578402  0.514529
   2012Q4  0.595443  0.670338  0.645557
   2013Q1  0.389000  0.595443  0.558296
   2013Q2  0.632672  0.389000  0.571863
   2013Q4  0.031375  0.632672  0.412123
2  2011Q4  0.860161       NaN       NaN
   2012Q1  0.337713  0.860161       NaN
   2012Q2  0.480819  0.337713       NaN
   2012Q3  0.167317  0.480819  0.461502
   2012Q4  0.650774  0.167317  0.409156
   2013Q1  0.197799  0.650774  0.374178
   2013Q2  0.417418  0.197799  0.358327
   2013Q4  0.705662  0.417418  0.492913
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I wasn't clear in my question that the moving average needs to be computed for each group. So for `id=2` the values associated with `2011Q4` through `2012Q2` should be missing

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly, thank you for clarifying!